# What does the output value mean when mit-scheme evaluates a list?

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

In the `mit-scheme` REPL if I evaluate

```
(list 1 2 3)
```

I get this the first time

```
;Value 13: (1 2 3)
```

then this the second time

```
;Value 14: (1 2 3)
```

and this the third time

```
;Value 15: (1 2 3)
```

Every time the value increments by one.

In other scheme REPLs I've noticed the `;Value xx` part isn't displayed at all.

What does the value mean? I'm guessing it's the memory address of the list? If so, why does it always start at 13 and why only show the address for lists?

A quick search of the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-user/index.html) didn't help me.

I'm running `mit-scheme` version 9.1.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does the value mean?

The number displayed is the hash of the list.

```
1 ]=> (define my-list '(1 2 3))

;Value: my-list

1 ]=> my-list

;Value 13: (1 2 3)

1 ]=> (hash-object my-list)

;Value: 13
```

(For MIT Scheme before version 10, use `hash` instead of `hash-object`).

For details on hashing, see section about [Object Hashing](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/stable/mit-scheme-ref/Object-Hashing.html#Object-Hashing) of the [MIT/GNU Scheme](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/) reference.

> why [does it] only show the address for lists?

It's the way the authors of MIT Scheme chose to write the REPL. Lines 491-500 of [`src/runtime/rep.scm`](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/mit-scheme.git/tree/src/runtime/rep.scm?h=release-9.1#n491) from the MIT Scheme 9.1.1 source code deal with printing REPL results:

```
(define (default/repl-write object s-expression environment repl)
  (port/write-result (cmdl/port repl)
             s-expression
             object
             (and repl:write-result-hash-numbers?
              (object-pointer? object)
              (not (interned-symbol? object))
              (not (number? object))
              (object-hash object))
             environment))
```

As you can see, the object hash is displayed in the REPL only if the object is a pointer (which is an implementation detail), is not an interned symbol, and is not a number.

Comment: Why is the hash not based on the contents of the list? The first list created will always give a hash of 13 regardless of its contents. However, another list with the same contents will generate a different hash. Seems a bit counter intuitive.

Comment: @David It's an implementation detail, but the "hash of a list" is actually the hash of the pointer to the list. In MIT Scheme, the hash of an object is something like the memory address of the object except that the "hash number, unlike an object's address, is unchanged by garbage collection" (source: section 11.5 *Object Hashing* from MIT Scheme 9.1.1's reference).